# I am trying to make switchable tab but during compiling vba i am getting error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Sub TabPer()
With Sheet3
.Shapes("PerOn").Visible = msoCTrue
.Shapes("PerOff").Visible = msoFalse

.Shapes("BusOn").Visible = msoCFalse
.Shapes("BusOff").Visible = msoCTrue

.Range("A:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Range("N:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True


End With
End Sub

Sub TabBus()
With Sheet3
.Shapes("PerOn").Visible = msoCFalse
.Shapes("PerOff").Visible = msoTrue

.Shapes("BusOn").Visible = msoCTrue
.Shapes("BusOff").Visible = msoCFalse

.Range("A:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
.Range("N:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code and tell us what kind of error you're getting.

Comment: Try `msoTrue`, `msoFalse` In Excel VBA,  `msoCFalse` is not a valid constant